# Control the execution of a Function

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an action from my UIButton that calls a function. Eg:

```
-(void)function:(id)sender{
    // execute some code here
}
```

- When I click on the UIButton this function will start
- If I click again, and the function isn't finished - I would like to stop the function, and call it again
- If the function has finished, just call the function again

Is this possible?

Comment: What is that "something" you are talking about? Like a process that needs lots of time to be executed? Are you performing it asynchronously?

Comment: what the mean by stop the function?

Comment: i have some task to exec inside this function. If this task is executing, and i try to click in button, i want to cancel this task, and start it again

Comment: @iDroid Yes, I'm using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 1), ^{
        });

Comment: Can u explain the task which is executing inside the function ? Would be better if u write the code inside the function also.

Comment: we don't have any idea about what you are executing in your function, and how to stop that execution....

Comment: are you able to stop the execution of function?

Comment: the execution is get/post something in my service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can work with an ivar to indicate that function has not finished executing. Something like:

```
    BOOL isFinished;

    -(void)function:(id)sender{

            if(!isFinished) {
                // stop your process
                // start it again
                // and indicate that it's running (isFinished is still false)
            }
            else {
                isFinished = NO;
                // just start your process
            }
        }
```

When your function/process has finished, set `isFinished = YES;` from there.

Comment: this works..thank you! But is it possible do it without add a global BOOL?

Comment: U can set the sender state from not selected to selected or vice versa.
`if([sender isSelected]) 
{
                // stop your process
                // start it again
                // and indicate that it's running (isFinished is still false)
            }
            else {
                [sender setSelected:YES];
                // just start your process
            }`
When the process completes, set the button `setSelected` to NO